# Does real programming follow the same basic control structures?

Tags: control-structure

I'm still a beginner and learning. In tutorials there's usually examples like: using "If...else" to check if the login password is correct, else show "incorrect password" or anything like that.
My question is: do programmers really use such basic control structures in this simple way in final real life projects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although both the question an this answer might be considered off-topic, the answer is *yes, programmers do use basic control structures*, as I can tell from my experience as a professional programmer. Basically, larger systems of software are just more complex than smaller programs, but do not use substantially different language constructs.

That being said, there are various techniques to organize things like *structured programming* or *object-oriented programming*, but at the end of the day some basic control structures have to be executed somewhere.